# Excel CountIF Formula to Group List with 2 Limitations

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I would very much appreciate your guidance. 
I have a list of data with a sequential UniqueID and an Attribute.
I need to divide it by Attribute into as few batches as possible but the max in the batch is 60 and each batch can only have a max of 25 of the same Attribute.

My effort on this was with two columns & sample data:

```
UniqueID ------- Attribute

ID0001   ------- abc123 (for the 1st 100 lines ID0001-ID0100)

ID0101   ------- def456 (for the 2nd 100 lines ID0101-ID0200)

ID0201   ------- ghi789 (for the 3rd 100 lines ID0201-ID0300)
```

In Col C to Countif the max of 25:

```
=CONCATENATE("firstlimit-",INT(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B2)/25)+1)
```

Then in Col D to Countif based on the formula in Col C up to a max of 60:

```
=CONCATENATE("secondlimit-",INT(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,C2)/60)+1) & " - " & C2
```

That would leave the batches labelled as "secondlimit-1 - firstlimit-1", etc. as can be seen from the following pivot of the results.

The issue I see with my approach is that, from group “secondlimit-2 - firstlimit-1” my approach causes the results to be restricted to building the groups from the leftovers of the first countif – What I would like to see is “secondlimit-2 - firstlimit-1 with 25”, etc. because I want a formula to fill the batches to both limits and reduce the number of batches.

```
Row Labels --------------------abc123--def456--ghi789--Grand Total

secondlimit-1 - firstlimit-1 ----25----25----10----60

secondlimit-1 - firstlimit-2 ----25----25----10----60

secondlimit-1 - firstlimit-3 ----25----25----10----60

secondlimit-1 - firstlimit-4 ----25----25----10----60

secondlimit-2 - firstlimit-1 ----00----00----15----15

secondlimit-2 - firstlimit-2 ----00----00----15----15

secondlimit-2 - firstlimit-3 ----00----00----15----15

secondlimit-2 - firstlimit-4 ----00----00----15----15

Grand Total --------------------100----100----100----300
```

Randomizing the list using the attributes doesn't fix this and I cannot see how I could use CountIFS to get the results I need. I have found it difficult to describe my requirements in any searches. Thank you.

Comment: So is the issue that second-limit should go up by 1 every time the ID changes?

Comment: Hi SJR, I have edited the post to hopefully give more clarity on the count and batch names.

Comment: I think it would help if you posted your desired results.

Comment: Hi SJR, Desired result: Max 60 entries, with a max 25 of the same Attribute per batch. My method works for the first 4 lines of the result pivot table above where there are enough lines with the Attributes to fill a batch. However, my method is not working to minimise the total number of batches. From batch "secondlimit-2 - firstlimit-1" onwards, where there are limited lines with the same attribute, the method I used results in 15 where desired is 25 (the max count of the same Attribute). Overall, instead of the last 4 batches of 15 I would like to achieve 2 of 25, 1 with the remaining 10.

Comment: Thanks to anyone who has looked at this so far. From the time I spent on this I expect that I need some form of single nested statement. My current workaround is to take out the data counted as "secondlimit-2..." into a new sheet with the same formula (in the example above that gives me the 2 batches of 25 and one of 10). I'll keep trying, if I get the solution I'll add it here. I'm going to try some VBA code to build an array of unique Attributes and loop through the list with counters to divide the batches that way. Any advice welcome & thanks again.